# Detect iOS Browser (Iphone,Ipod,Ipad) Change DIV from FLASH TO HTML5

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html, ipod

I want to  change ONLY the **DIV** if site is open in iPad,iPod,iPhone **Safari**
in short i want to add HTML5 Music Player if site is open in Ios Device
is it possible to only change the DIV n not the whole page ? after browser detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I want to change ONLY the DIV if site is open in iPad,iPod,iPhone Safari`

The trend these days has been **away** from browser detection, and **towards** feature-support detection.

Google has some Javascript code to detect Flash support (as do others, but this is a decent example):

http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleDetectFlash

`is it possible to only change the DIV n not the whole page`

Absolutely, this is pretty standard javascript stuff. There are a million different ways to do this. If you're using jQuery, I'd start by looking at some of the DOM manipulation functions: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ and going from there. Of course, this is easily possible without jQuery or any other JS framework. But that seems like it's beyond the scope of this question.